# "The requested URL /projects was not found on this server" when I am trying to run redmine(Ubuntu 16.04, Apache2, Passenger )

Tags: apache, passenger, ubuntu-16.04, redmine

I installed passenger over apache in order to run redmine (ROR application)on Ubuntu 16.04.
I setuped everything as described in the documentation but I always get the "The requested URL /projects was not found on this server" 
If I add a simple html page it loads fine.
The site configuration is teh following:

```
<VirtualHost ip:80>
ServerName redmine.domain.com
ServerAlias www.redmine.domain.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerAlias webmail.redmine.domain.com
ServerAlias admin.redmine.domain.com
DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html/redmine
PassengerRuby /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/wrappers/ruby
RailsEnv production
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
<Directory "/home/user/public_html/redmine">
      Options FollowSymLinks
      Require all granted
      Allow from all
      Options -MultiViews
</Directory>
```

The error.log of apache shows the following:

```
[ N 2017-09-27 14:02:32.7396 7376/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1068 ]: Passenger core shutdown finished
[ N 2017-09-27 14:02:32.7504 7404/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1283 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ N 2017-09-27 14:02:32.7678 7408/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1083 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ N 2017-09-27 14:02:32.7681 7408/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:248 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ N 2017-09-27 14:02:32.7746 7408/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:830 ]: Passenger core online, PID 7408
[ N 2017-09-27 14:02:32.7895 7417/T1 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:537 ]: Starting Passenger UstRouter...
[ N 2017-09-27 14:02:32.7905 7417/T1 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:350 ]: Passenger UstRouter online, PID 7417
[Wed Sep 27 14:02:32.832157 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7398] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 Phusion_Passenger/5.1.8 OpenSSL/1.0.2g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Sep 27 14:02:32.832208 2017] [core:notice] [pid 7398] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[ N 2017-09-27 14:02:34.9949 7408/T8 age/Cor/SecurityUpdateChecker.h:374 ]: Security update check: no update found (next check in 24 hours)
```

Initially I was getting an error with autoindex which I disabled and now I do not get the error, but still no redmine page. Any Ideas or any other log you need?

Also the:

```
bundle exec passenger start
```

Reports the following:

```
=============== Phusion Passenger Standalone web server started ===============
PID file: /home/user/public_html/redmine/tmp/pids/passenger.3000.pid
Log file: /home/user/public_html/redmine/log/passenger.3000.log
Environment: development
Accessible via: http://0.0.0.0:3000/
You can stop Phusion Passenger Standalone by pressing Ctrl-C.

===============================================================================

[ N 2017-09-27 14:43:00.4493 13372/T7 age/Cor/SecurityUpdateChecker.h:374 ]: Security update check: no update found (next check in 24 hours)
App 13412 stdout:
App 13428 stdout:
Started HEAD "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-09-27 14:43:04 +0300
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
   (1.1ms)  SELECT MAX(`settings`.`updated_on`) FROM `settings`
  Setting Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'rest_api_enabled'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  AnonymousUser Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`type` IN ('AnonymousUser')  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Current user: anonymous
  Setting Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'login_required'  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0/login?back_url=http%3A%2F%2F0.0.0.0%2F
Filter chain halted as :check_if_login_required rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 180ms (ActiveRecord: 7.6ms)
```

after that when I go to

```
links http://0.0.0.0/login?back_url=http%3A%2F%2F0.0.0.0%2F
```

The page appear properly and I am able to login and work with it. Although from the redmine.domain.com I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your `DocumentRoot` probably should not point to the top level dir of your app: `/home/user/public_html/redmine` instead it should point to a dir with the static files that Apache should serve without help, and then the parent dir will be served as a ruby app; if the direct parent dir is not the top level dir of the ruby app (ie the one with `config.ru`) set `PassengerAppRoot` (https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengerapproot) to the dir that holds `config.ru` which in this case is likely: `/home/user/public_html/redmine`.

Answer (score 0):

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

from

DocumentRoot /var/www/html

to
DocumentRoot /var/www/